# Can I make the Column section not expand to fill the page in iReport

Tags: layout, jasper-reports, ireport

If my report only generates a handful of rows of data (not pages, just rows) then I would like to have my totals row appear immediately after the last row of data, instead of being forced to the bottom of the page.  How do I do that?  I have tried a page footer and a column footer and they both appear at the bottom of the page rather than right below the last line of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the root report properties there is a property called "Float column footer". If you turn that on, that should do the trick. Also make sure the data that you need to float up is in the column footer band.